# Assign object to interface in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I'm writing an application in Lazarus, where I use interfaces for MVVM design.

I have a IModel and IViewModel interfaces

```
IViewModel = interface
  function GetModel: IModel;
  procedure SetModel(AValue: IModel);
  property Model: IModel read GetModel write SetModel;
end; 

IModel = interface
end;
```

And I also have implementation for models

```
IMainModel = interface(IModel)
   ...
end;

TMainModel = TMainModel = class(TInterfacedObject, IMainModel)
   ...
end;
```

and for viewmodels

```
IMainViewModel = interface(IViewModel)
  ...
end;

TMainViewModel = class(TInterfacedObject, IMainViewModel)
private
  FModel: IModel;
  procedure SetModel(AValue: IModel);
  function GetModel: IModel;
  ...
public
  property Model: IModel read GetModel write SetModel; 
  ...
end;
```

When I try to assign an implementation to viewmodel

```
var LModel: TMainModel;
    LMainViewModel: TMainViewModel
begin
LMainViewModel.Model := LModel;
LMainView.ViewModel := LMainViewMode;
end;
```

I get a message:

VKCommunityMessenger.lpr(34,33) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got   "TMainModel", expected "IModel"

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Full source code of app is [here](https://github.com/Zawuza/VKCommunityMessenger). Latest commit contains this error.

Comment: `TMainModel` doesn't implement `IModel`. It implements `IMainModel`. Solve this by declaring the class like this: `TMainModel = class(TInterfacedObject, IModel, IMainModel)`. You will find many instances of this question under the Delphi tag. I am assuming that FPC behaves in the same way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan oh yes, it works!!! Thank you!!!